# Custom Method Security Expression Evaluator for Spring Boot 3 Webflux Application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-aop

I'd like to use method security annotations and a custom expression evaluator in my Spring Boot 3 Webflux application, and I'm not sure how to do it.

My endpoint with its method security annotation looks like this:

```
@GetMethod
@PreAuthorize(@foo.canAccess())
public Mono<FooResponse> computeFoos(Mono<FooRequest> fooRequest) {
    ...
}
```

My bean that handles this expression looks like this:

```
@Component("foo")
public class FooSecurityExpressionEvaluator {

    public Mono<Boolean> canAccess() {
        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                       .map(p -> true);
    }
}
```

I see an example in the [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/authorization/method.html) that uses a `Function` declared as a bean.  Can I do something similar with a bean that contains multiple methods?

Stack trace is as follows when I try to use my custom evaluator:

```
│ java.lang.IllegalStateException: No MethodInvocation found: Check that an AOP invocation is in progress and that the ExposeInvocationInterceptor is upfront in the interceptor chain. Specifically, note that advices with order HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE will │
│     at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.currentInvocation(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:74)                                                                                                                            │
│     Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:                                                                                                                                                                               │
│ Error has been observed at the following site(s):                                                                                                                                                                                                        │
│     *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.foo.FooController#computeFoos(Mono, ServerWebExchange) [DispatcherHandler]                                                                                                            │
│     *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]                                                                                                                                 │
│     *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]                                                                                                                          │
│     *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]                                                                                                                                │
│     *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]                                                                                                                             │
│     *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]                                                                                                                    │
│     *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]                                                                                                                               │
│     *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]                                                                                                                                      │
│     *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]                                                                                                                                     │
│     *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]                                                                                                   │
│     *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]                                                                                                                                                  │
│     *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]                                                                                                                                          │
│     *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/org" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]                                                                                                                                                                                       │
│ Original Stack Trace:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│         at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.currentInvocation(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:74)                                                                                                                        │
│         at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.getJoinPointMatch(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:655)                                                                                                                                       │
│         at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice.before(AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice.java:44)                                                                                                                                           │
│         at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:57)                                                                                                                         │
│         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173)                                                                                                                                     │
│         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)                                                                                                                                         │
│         at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.ReactiveMethodInvocationUtils.proceed(ReactiveMethodInvocationUtils.java:32)                                                                                                                │
│         at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeReactiveMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$2(AuthorizationManagerBeforeReactiveMethodInterceptor.java:113)                                                           │
│         at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)                                                                                                                                                                                 │
```

Comment: I also get the same error when I convert to using the example that the Spring Security documentation uses.  Note that the documentation references Spring Security 5.8.  I'm on 6.0.  Looks like the documentation needs to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had another Aspect intercepting my `computeFoos` method.  Once I removed that, this security check works as described in the question.

I tried to adjust the ordering of the interceptors (I set the `@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity(order = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`) but that didn't seem to work.